# a function median in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am new to Scheme and I am using Dr.Racket to try to find the median of the list.

If the length of list L is odd, the function median returns the median element in the list. If the length of L is even, the function median returns 0. 
example

```
(median ‘(1)) returns 1
(median ‘(1 2)) returns 0
(median ‘(1 2 3)) returns 2
(median ‘( 1 2 3 4) returns 0
```

i am only allowed to use

```
- null?
- car
- cdr
- else
- = 
- +
- median
- cond
- if
- user defined names (for my variables)
- integer literals
- parentheses
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts after you've got answers from people - it stops future readers from benefiting from their time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved using the [tortoise and hare algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare), provided that a helper inner procedure is allowed - we need to pass two parameters for this to work. Other than that, all the restrictions are enforced:

```
(define (median lst)
  (define (median tortoise hare)
    (cond ((null? hare) 0)
          ((null? (cdr hare)) (car tortoise))
          (else (median (cdr tortoise) (cdr (cdr hare))))))
  (median lst lst))
```

It works as expected:

```
(median '(1))       ; returns 1
(median '(1 2))     ; returns 0
(median '(1 2 3))   ; returns 2
(median '(1 2 3 4)) ; returns 0
```

Comment: We are not allowed to use two functions... it should be something like(define median (lambda (<list L followed by parameters of your choice 

initially set to zero>)

 (cond

)))
and it should have only one recursive function
...is there a way?

Comment: Can you please help with this. I am stuck .

Comment: @CCC we need two parameters for the above to work, that's the only requirement for the algorithm. To use a single function, then use only the innermost function I defined, that is: `(define (median tortoise hare) ... )` and call it as `(median lst lst)`.

Comment: All auxiliary parameters must be numeric (not lists) and should have initial values set to zero. For example, if L is ‘(1 2 3) and you decide to use one additional auxiliary parameters, median should be called (median '(1 2 3 4) 0 ). How will this work for the innermost function?

Comment: @CCC Sorry, but this can't be done using the tortoise and hare algorithm.

Comment: Lopez Is there any other solution to this problem?